# A * search algorithm in networking

Tags: routing

I'm not entirely sure if this question has been asked before, so apologies if it has.

I'm studying computer science at university and I've had two modules: Data Communication and Networking; Artificial Intelligence.

In networking we've been learning about routing and connecting routers together in order to transfer data (mainly discussing different types of protocols).

In AI, we used the A* Search as a path finding algorithm from a start node to a goal node in a graph with walls and traps.

My main question is: **Is it possible for A* Search to be used in routing?**

I understand that you would need to identify a form of cost between network nodes and find a suitable heuristic to do so. I'm more interested to know if something like that could work, and if not, then how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A * is an extension of the Dijkstra algorithm that used by some routing protocols, e.g. OSPF and IS-IS.

It is certainly possible to create a new routing protocol that uses A *, but it would really need to add something new to find any acceptance.

---

**Edit:**

In networking, routing is handled by routers. A node will know if the destination node is on a different network. If it is, then the node sends the traffic to its configured gateway (router).

A router has a routing table where it looks up the destination address to find the next interface to which the traffic should be sent. The routing table may be implemented as a memory structure (lookup table, tree, trie, etc.) or in hardware (CAM, TCAM, etc.).

The interesting part is how a routing table is populated. Routers learn about routes three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Routing protocols

A routing protocol is where the algorithms are used.

It really is not in the best interest of the network for a node to determine which path its traffic should take.